# X server randomly restarts

Tags: linux, debian, cinnamon

I'm running a Debian 9 kiosk with Cinnamon and Chrome browsers. It works fine until it reboots itself without any apparent reason. When this happens, it normally does 2 or 3 restarts in a row and then keeps working fine for a couple of days until it happens again.

I've checked my `/var/log/syslog` and all I can find there is this:

```
lots of cronjobs without noticeable errors...
.....
Jun 30 21:30:46 myuser x-session-manager[728]: WARNING: t+185522.72248s: Requesting system shutdown...
Jun 30 21:30:46 myuser x-session-manager[728]: WARNING: t+185522.72265s: Attempting to shutdown using systemd...
......
shuts down, restarts and work for a 50 minutes and then...
again, no noticeable error in here...
......
Jun 30 22:20:58 myuser x-session-manager[720]: WARNING: t+72.48357s: Requesting system shutdown...
Jun 30 22:20:58 myuser x-session-manager[720]: WARNING: t+72.48380s: Attempting to shutdown using systemd...
```

I was not able to find any documentation on why the X session could want to restart my system.

Would appreciate any tip on how to debug this issue.

PS: The temperatures are fine, about 54°C on peaks.

Comment: Do you have a UPS?

Comment: Yes, but is an external unit without communication with the linux box, so the OS does not receive any alert from the UPS unit. And anyway I've checked it to found no alarms on the last weeks.

Comment: Another possibility: Bad RAM, which flips a particular bit in a particular configuration, which causes a program to misbehave. If it's a program that's loaded early, like the X session manager, it'll get loaded into the same place. I just had a similar error (though not the X session manager), and memtest86+ didn't find anything, but changing the RAM fixed it. Easy to test if you have more than one RAM stick (remove the "lower" one).

Comment: Makes sense... This box is 6 hours away from me... but if the issue persists and I had to go there I'll try this!

Comment: Are you 100% sure it's not triggered manually by some "smart" user? I'd also look at `dmesg -T` and `/var/log/X.org.0.log` to see if there is any "strange" things there which would hint at H/W problems. I mean, I did experience H/W problems but for me, they (always) resulted in lockups or kernel panics, but here we experience _graceful software-initiated shutdown._ So I'd work from there.

Comment: Regarding that "smart user" thing—for instance, you might have the "magic SysRq" enabled (and it's enabled by default in Debian), and that user is used to hit `Alt-SysRq-k` to kill the X session (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) for more).

Comment: @kostix feeling dumb in here. never heard about "magic SysRq" before (even that key is indeed on my keyboard in front of me)... thanks for your sugestion, but this terminal has no keyboard, all interaction happens on a touch screen on a page open in chrome browser.

Comment: No reason to feel dumb here: when I've got the first chance to lay my hands on an IBM PC-compatible machine—and that were in early '90s—those SysRq, Scroll Lock and Pause/Break keys had already essentially lost its original meaning as they were not used by anything in MS-DOS, I reckon. :-)